# Identify and Copy latest files in directory

Tags: vbscript

Everyday around 7 AM there are **3** csv exports extracted into a specific folder and the file names are exactly the same each day except everyday the prefix of the file name is amended to the current date.

Example:

**16-02-2018_Test1** will change to **17-02-2018_Test1**

**16-02-2018_Test2** will change to **17-02-2018_Test2**

**16-02-2018_Test3** will change to **17-02-2018_Test3**

The file itself is not replaced, the new file with the current date is instead added to this folder.

What I need to do is identify the 3 extracts each day and copy them to a sub-folder. The best way I thought of doing this is by identifying the date at which the file was last modified.

I have the below VBS code I found and helps identifies the latest file in a directory and I added a line that will copy that file to a new directory.

The issue however, is that the code only identifies 1 file instead of 3 and I can only copy 1 file instead of 3. If anyone has better code to help me achieve the desired result **or** alternatively can help modify the existing code to achieve the desired result.

```
sPath = "C:\Users\Desktop\Test\"

Const sToDir = "C:\Users\Desktop\Test\NewFolder\"

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

sNewestFile = GetNewestFile(sPath)

If sNewestFile <> "" Then

   WScript.Echo "Newest file is " & sNewestFile

   dFileModDate = oFSO.GetFile(sNewestFile).DateLastModified
   If DateDiff("n", dFileModDate, Now) > 60 Then
     oFSO.CopyFile sNewestFile, sToDir
   End If

Else
   WScript.Echo "Directory is empty"
End If


Function GetNewestFile(ByVal sPath)

   sNewestFile = Null   ' init value

   Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sPath)
   Set oFiles = oFolder.Files

   ' enumerate the files in the folder, finding the newest file
   For Each oFile In oFiles
     On Error Resume Next
     If IsNull(sNewestFile) Then
       sNewestFile = oFile.Path
       dPrevDate = oFile.DateLastModified
     Elseif dPrevDate < oFile.DateLastModified Then
       sNewestFile = oFile.Path
       dPrevDate = oFile.DateLastModified
     End If
     On Error Goto 0
   Next

   If IsNull(sNewestFile) Then sNewestFile = ""

   GetNewestFile = sNewestFile

End Function
```

Comment: Have you tried parsing names of the files to extract the date?

Comment: Hi @hrust No I have not. How would having the names help identify the most recent files?

Comment: Isn't this `16-02-2018_Test1.csv` an example of the filename you're processing?  If you have files with the date in their names then it's very simple to locate required ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for the help, I found the answer on a different thread. Here is the link: [Copy 2 latest text file from a source folder to destination folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20780882/copy-2-latest-text-file-from-a-source-folder-to-destination-folder?rq=1)

Below is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim FolderToCheck, FolderDestination, FileExt, mostRecent, noFiles, fso, fileList, file, filecounter, oShell, strHomeFolder

' Enumerate current user's home path - we will use that by default later if nothing specified in commandline
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strHomeFolder = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%")

'Variables -----
folderToCheck = strHomeFolder & "\Desktop\MY\MMS"           ' Folder Source to check for recent files to copy FROM
folderDestination = strHomeFolder & "\Desktop\New"          ' Destination Folder where to copy files TO

fileExt = "txt"     ' Extension we are searching for
mostRecent = 2      ' Most Recent number of files to copy
' --------------


PreProcessing()     ' Retrieve Command Line Parameters

' Display what we are intending on doing
wscript.echo "Checking Source: " & FolderToCheck 
wscript.echo "For Files of type: " & FileExt
wscript.echo "Copying most recent "& mostRecent &" file(s) to: " & FolderDestination & "."
wscript.echo 

noFiles = TRUE

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set fileList = CreateObject("ADOR.Recordset")
fileList.Fields.append "name", 200, 255
fileList.Fields.Append "date", 7
fileList.Open

If fso.FolderExists(FolderToCheck) Then 
    For Each file In fso.GetFolder(FolderToCheck).files
     If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(file)) = LCase(FileExt) then
       fileList.AddNew
       fileList("name").Value = File.Path
       fileList("date").Value = File.DateLastModified
       fileList.Update
       If noFiles Then noFiles = FALSE
     End If
    Next
    If Not(noFiles) Then 
        wscript.echo fileList.recordCount & " File(s) found. Sorting and copying last " & mostRecent &"..."
        fileList.Sort = "date DESC"
        If Not(fileList.EOF) Then 
            fileList.MoveFirst
            If fileList.recordCount < mostRecent Then 
                wscript.echo "WARNING: " & mostRecent &" file(s) specified but only " & fileList.recordcount & " file(s) match criteria. Adjusted to " & fileList.RecordCount & "."
                mostRecent = fileList.recordcount
            End If

            fileCounter = 0
            Do Until fileList.EOF Or fileCounter => mostRecent
                If Not(fso.FolderExists(folderDestination)) Then 
                    wscript.echo "Destination Folder did not exist. Creating..."
                    fso.createFolder folderDestination
                End If
                fso.copyfile fileList("name"), folderDestination & "\", True
                wscript.echo  fileList("date").value & vbTab & fileList("name")
                fileList.moveNext
                fileCounter = fileCounter + 1
            Loop
        Else
            wscript.echo "An unexpected error has occured."
        End If
    Else
        wscript.echo "No matching """ & FileExt &""" files were found in """ & foldertocheck & """ to copy."
    End If
Else
    wscript.echo "Error: Source folder does not exist """ & foldertocheck & """."
End If

fileList.Close

Function PreProcessing
    Dim source, destination, ext, recent

    ' Initialize some variables
    Set source = Nothing
    Set destination = Nothing
    Set ext = Nothing
    Set recent = Nothing

    'Get Command Line arguments
    ' <scriptname>.vbs /Source:"C:\somepath\somefolder" /Destination:"C:\someotherpath\somefolder" /ext:txt /recent:2

    source = wscript.arguments.Named.Item("source")
    destination = wscript.arguments.Named.Item("destination")
    ext = wscript.arguments.Named.Item("ext")
    recent = wscript.arguments.Named.Item("recent")

    If source <> "" Then FolderToCheck = source
    If destination <> "" Then FolderDestination = destination
    If ext <> "" Then FileExt = ext
    If recent <> "" Then mostRecent = int(recent)

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Invest some work in a useful format class and

- just look for the 3 files of the day (FileExists)
- if they are not there, look for the previous day's files

or

- search for the newest file and build all three file names from the prefix

In code:

```
Option Explicit

' stolen from https://stackoverflow.com/a/21643663/603855
' added formatTwo; left as exercise: formatThree
Class cFormat
  Private m_oSB
  Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_oSB = CreateObject("System.Text.StringBuilder")
  End Sub ' Class_Initialize
  Public Function formatOne(sFmt, vElm)
    m_oSB.AppendFormat sFmt, vElm
    formatOne = m_oSB.ToString()
    m_oSB.Length = 0
  End Function ' formatOne
  Public Function formatTwo(sFmt, vElm1, vElm2)
    m_oSB.AppendFormat_2 sFmt, vElm1, vElm2
    formatTwo = m_oSB.ToString()
    m_oSB.Length = 0
  End Function ' formatOne
  Public Function formatArray(sFmt, aElms)
    m_oSB.AppendFormat_4 sFmt, (aElms)
    formatArray = m_oSB.ToString()
    m_oSB.Length = 0
  End Function ' formatArray
End Class ' cFormat

Dim oFmt : Set oFmt = New cFormat
Dim sFmt : sFmt = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}_Test{1}"
Dim dToday : dToday = Date()
Dim i 
WScript.Echo "file names expected today " & oFmt.formatOne("({0:yyyy-MMM-d}).", dToday) 
For i = 1 To 3
    WScript.Echo oFmt.FormatTwo(sFmt, dToday, i)
Next
WScript.Echo oFmt.formatArray("look for {0} if {1} is missing on the {2:dd}th after 7 AM" _ 
   , Array(oFmt.FormatTwo(sFmt, DateAdd("d", -1, dToday), 1), oFmt.FormatTwo(sFmt, dToday, 1), dToday))

Dim sFnd : sFnd = oFmt.FormatTwo(sFmt, dToday, 2) 
WScript.Echo "if your GetNewestFile() finds " & sFnd & ", copy:"
For i = 1 To 3
    WScript.Echo Left(sFnd, Len(sFnd) - 1) & i 
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 48866113.vbs
file names expected today (2018-Feb-19).
19-02-2018_Test1
19-02-2018_Test2
19-02-2018_Test3
look for 18-02-2018_Test1 if 19-02-2018_Test1 is missing on the 19th after 7 AM
if your GetNewestFile() finds 19-02-2018_Test4, copy:
19-02-2018_Test1
19-02-2018_Test2
19-02-2018_Test3
```